# How to upgrade Browser of Pepper Robot's Tablet?

Tags: pepper

My current browser is Chrome 39. How to upgrade it to newest version?
I really need to upgrade it to newest version which compatible with website I want to open.

My Pepper version is 1.8a and uses NAOqi 2.5.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to upgrade python pepper's chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update Pepper's browser with NAOqi 2.5 and versions of Pepper below 1.8. But it is possible if you upgrade your Pepper to NAOqi 2.9.